# Users higher in the role is getting access to records owned by role below them when Grant Access Using Hierarchies is unchecked

Tags: sharing-rule, owd

I am testing on how the Grant access using hierarchies work.
Here is the setting I have as of now for testing -
Two users

1. **User 1** -
   **Role** - Director, Direct Sales
2. **User 2** -
   **Role** - Western Sales Team

As per the role chart the **Western Sales Team** comes under **Director, Direct Sales**.

Now I created a custom object called Property -

**OWD Setting** - Private
**Grant Access Using Hierarchies** - Unchecked

Now when User 2 creates a property record it can be viewed by User 1 even when the Grant access using hierarchies option is unchecked.

Please advise!

Comment: Did you create any sharing rules for "Property"? Or did you perform any manual sharing of specific Property records?

Comment: No sharing rules created or manual sharing done.

Comment: Anybody has an answer to this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a reason it's not working as you might expect.

Comment: Have you added the Sharing button to the page layout and clicked on it to see the sharing for that record?  Is the User1 in any profile or permission set that has View All on the object or View All Data system permission?